# How to access javascript variable in a jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to access javascript code in my jsp file. I have included that javascript file in my jsp page.

javascript file abc.js has following line of code:

```
var dynamicDiv = 'Your leave is approved';
```

and my jsp file aaa.jsp has

```
<script src="abc.js">
</script>  


<% String st = "<script> dynamicDiv </script>";
out.println(" value = " + st); %>
```

Comment: @Vikrant added the sample code

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript variable is on client side, JSP variables is on server side, so you can't access javascript variables in JSP.

You can store values in a hidden field somthing like this

Clinet side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var element = document.getElementById("myInput");
element.value = "some value here";
</script>
<form action="YourFile.jsp" method="POST">
<input id="myInput" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Server side(YourFile.jsp):

```
<%
if (request.getParameter("myInput") != null) { %>
 Your value: <%=request.getParameter("myInput")%>
<%   
} 
%>
```

Answer (score -1):

it's impossible to access a client side variable through jsp

Comment: @AtanuCSE How exactly is this a question? You need to be a bit more awake while doing reviews.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this answer needs to be deleted, it may or may not be a good/correct answer but it is an answer to the question.

Comment: @Lundin you're right. my bad. I misread it